# i got undefined when i consoled console.log

Tags: node.js

when i consoled err.kind i got value for it
but when i set (error = { ...err };) then i did console
i had undefined in my console ?!

```
      module.exports = (err,req,res,next)=>{
       err.statusCode = err.statusCode || 500 ;
        err.state = err.state ||"error";
        if(process.env.NODE_ENV === "development"){
            console.log(err.name)
        DevError(err,res);
        }
        else if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== "development"){ 
        let error = { ...err };
            if(error.kind === "CastError") error= wrongID(error)
           console.log(error.kind)
        cliError(error,res);
         
        }
    }
```

Comment: Because probably you have overwritten `error` by `error= wrongID(error)` and wrongID() doesn't return object with `kind` property.

Comment: how should i write it ?

Comment: Can you paste your wrongID(error) function body in the post?

Comment: const wrongID = err=>{
    const message  =`no document for that id ${err.value}`
    return new AppError(message,400)
}

Comment: what is AppError class?

Comment: i guess its all about define of error = { ... err }; i got it because of that line 
otherwise its working fine

Comment: class AppError extends Error{
    constructor(message , statusCode){
    super(message);
    this.statusCode = statusCode ;
    this.status = `${statusCode}`.startsWith('4') ? 'Fail' : 'error';
    this.isOpreational =true ;
    Error.captureStackTrace(this ,this.constructor);
}
}
module.exports = AppError ;

Comment: Add new param to constructor() off AppError - i.e. `kind`. Then, add bellow this.kind = kind; Should be working. You have to also change `return new AppError(message,400)` to `return new AppError(message,400,err.kind)`

Comment: It's worth noting if you have a condition like `if (x == y)` then just use an `else` for the opposite case. Stating `else if (x != y)` is just plain bizarre. What else could it be?

Answer (score 0):

This is a rest destructuring issue where only the enumerable properties are getting copied over. Search for "Rest in Object Destructuring" here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Consider this:

```
const example1 = { a: 1 };

// this creates a non-enumerable property "b"
Object.defineProperty(example1, 'b', { value: 2 });

const example2 = { ...example1 };

console.log(example1.a);
// 1
console.log(example1.b);
// 2
console.log(example2.a);
// 1
console.log(example2.b);
// undefined
```

Comment: in my situation console.log(error.kind)  should appears

Comment: The short answer is you cannot use `error = { ...err };` to preserve the `kind` property. The reason for that behavior is explained above.